# Pear::MDB2 - get last executed query

Tags: php, pear, mdb2

I have to use Pear MDB2 but don't know how to get the last executed query. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS you can see in this link: [https://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/docs/latest/MDB2/MDB2_Driver_Common.html#var$last_query](https://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/docs/latest/MDB2/MDB2_Driver_Common.html#var%24last_query) you have a variable called $last_query that stores the last query sent to the driver.

I have not checked it, but based on the documentation you can use:

```
$mdb2 =& MDB2::connect('YOUR_DSN');
if (PEAR::isError($mdb2)) {
    die($mdb2->getMessage());
}

// Proceed with a query...
$res =& $mdb2->query('SELECT * FROM clients');

echo $mdb2->last_query;
```